# ImportError with from . import x on simple python files

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I wanted to port some code from python 2 to python 3 and it failed on an import error. So I tried to get rid of the porting itself and focus on the import by creating 2 basic python files to test with. However I can't even get those to work.

So I have 2 files

test.py:

```
print('Test works')
```

and test2.py:

```
from . import test
```

The result however is this error in Pycharm:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'test' from '__main__'
>   (C:/Users/Username/test2.py)

In Ubuntu Shell:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test2.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from . import test1 SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

How can I solve it?

Comment: tried from .test import test?

Comment: @JordyRitzen, you can still use `from . import test` syntax of import. You just need to change the folder structure. That syntax works perfectly if you are going to design a package. Just have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html. I have already tried it.

Answer (score 6):

This "folder structure matters" is a large problem in python3. Your folder structure should NOT matter when coding, but should be referenced properly.

I've just resorted to using if/else depending on if ran locally or as part of a module:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": # Local Run
    import test
else: # Module Run, When going production - delete if/else
    from . import test
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python3

test2.py:

```
import test
```

test.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Test works')
```

**If you want to print "Test works" in other file**
test2.py:

```
import test
test.main()
```

test.py:

```
def main():
    print('Test works')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! If mine is correct please select it as correct answer

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. Also it'd mean that there's a class test inside test won't it?

Comment: is there only one line in both the .py files?

Comment: I posted all of the code. It already fails with just those 2 lines of code. It must be something very simple but I don't know what.

Comment: to print "Test works" add that in a function say main() and call it under __main__
and call that from test2.py by "test.main()"

Comment: The problem is not that I want to print something. The import is the problem. And even when I try your code for printing it throws me the same error.

Comment: may be because you are importing the module that has similar name to built-in modules. Can you try to change the file test.py to some other non-related to built-in modules name?

Answer (score 1):

The folder structure matters. You didn't name your module; I will call it `foo`. Put things in the right place:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch foo/__init__.py
$ mv /some/place/{test1,test2}.py foo/
```

Notice that `python -c 'import test'` works already, even before you wrote your test.py file. To avoid confusion I recommend naming your file test1.py.

The way you call your code matters. Verify that `.` dot is in `sys.path`:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=.
$ python -m foo.test1
```

Alternatively this should work, if you prefer:

```
$ python foo/test1.py
```

EDIT:

I answered question #1, and OP now asks question #2, about this diagnostic:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'test' from '**main**' (C:/Users/Username/test2.py)

Please organize your files in the proper structure. You need to put test2.py within a `foo/` directory (or whatever you care to call it). You need to create an empty `foo/__init__.py` file, as that is important for the `import` machinery.

Also, the PYTHONPATH env var in the calling environment matters. In addition to the command line environment, you have now introduced a PyCharm environment. Take care to configure PyCharm correctly for your project. Click on Preferences -> Project Structure and ensure that `foo` shows up as a Source Folder. You can debug this in either environment by executing these lines:

```
import sys
import pprint
pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

Since `import test` would succeed even without your project being in place, I recommend you rename to `test1.py` and use `import test1` so you can be sure you're pulling in *your* code.

Comment: when I run it as python3 -m foo.test2 in the parent folder of foo it works.
But when I run the python3 foo/test2.py it crashes and provides me the error as shown in my updated question. (Why does python 3 gives me so much trouble haha)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and ended up removing the "from . " that was added from the 2to3 conversion script.